# Capturing multiple occurrences of javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dust.js

I'm writing a node module and I want to find all the partials used by a dust template.

I have

```
regex = /\{\s*\>\s*("[^"]*").*\}/
```

and

```
test = " something { > \"templatename\" randomchars\" key=\"{random}\" } random { > \"base/templatename2\" thing=\"random\" }"
```

I want to capture both `templatename` and `base/templatename2`.

I tried with and without the `g` flag and I tried `regex.exec(test)` twice and `test.match(regex)` but neither of them give me both. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `.*` not greedy (`.*?`) so that it won't cover the following template names :

```
var matches = test.match(/\{\s*>\s*("[^"]*").*?\}/g)
```

This gives you the matches, not the submatches. To get the groups, use `exec` :

```
var r = /\{\s*>\s*("[^"]*").*?\}/g, m;
while (m = r.exec(test)) {
  console.log(m[1]); 
}
```

Side notice : there was no need to escape the `>`.